# Selecting Max Value for an Existing Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

firstly, here's my code

```
SELECT dbo.tblPat.pID, dbo.tblRec.rID,
right(rPCheck, LEN(rPCheck) - (CHARINDEX('|', rPCheck))) as pCheck,
right(rGP, LEN(rGP) - (CHARINDEX('|', rGP))) as GPCheck
FROM
dbo.tblPat INNER JOIN
dbo.tblPatRecords ON dbo.tblPat.pID = dbo.tblPatRecords.pID INNER JOIN
dbo.tblRec ON dbo.tblPatRecords.rID = dbo.tblRec.rID
WHERE     
(DATEPART(dw, dbo.tblRec.rDateRecAdd) IN (5, 6, 7)) 
AND (dbo.tblRec.rGP <> N'0') 
AND (dbo.tblRec.rPCheck <> N'0')
AND right(rPCheck, LEN(rPCheck) - (CHARINDEX('|', rPCheck))) > right(rGP, LEN(rGP) - (CHARINDEX('|', rGP)))
ORDER BY dbo.tblPat.pID, dbo.tblRec.rID
```

Whih basicallybrings back data in this format

```
39  366 26/06/2008 16:54:35 26/06/2008 15:04:53
39  368 27/06/2008 09:33:55 27/06/2008 08:57:07
39  369 27/06/2008 09:35:14 27/06/2008 08:57:07
39  370 27/06/2008 09:36:34 27/06/2008 08:57:07
39  371 27/06/2008 09:37:33 27/06/2008 08:57:07
39  372 27/06/2008 09:37:33 27/06/2008 08:57:07
39  373 27/06/2008 09:37:33 27/06/2008 08:57:07
39  374 27/06/2008 09:37:33 27/06/2008 08:57:07
*39 397 27/06/2008 13:13:49 27/06/2008 12:48:25*
92  46310   19/08/2008 15:52:50 03/10/2008 14:50:00
92  46313   19/08/2008 15:52:50 03/10/2008 14:52:50
92  46315   19/08/2008 15:52:50 03/10/2008 14:52:50
92  46558   19/08/2008 15:52:50 03/10/2008 19:26:04
92  46559   19/08/2008 15:52:50 03/10/2008 19:26:04
92  46623   04/10/2008 10:46:39 03/10/2008 19:26:04
*92 46632   04/10/2008 10:46:39 03/10/2008 19:26:04*
```

As you may have guessedm I need to pick out the last entry for each pID so in this case, I need

```
39  397 27/06/2008 13:13:49 27/06/2008 12:48:25
92  46632   04/10/2008 10:46:39 03/10/2008 19:26:04
```

Any help would be great. I could cheat and turn this into a view and then do another view but I want to be as clean as possible

Comment: By entry do you mean you want to see all the columns with the highest rID for each pID or do you mean you just want to know the highest rID for each pID?

Comment: Either one - all columns might be more useful but I can live with just the highest rID for each pID

Comment: what SQL Server version are you using?, 2000, 2005 or 2008?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of the JOIN onto tblPatRecords directly, try replacing with a join onto a subquery, so e.g. replace your FROM clause to this:

```
FROM dbo.tblPat INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT pID, MAX(rID) AS rID
    FROM dbo.tblPatRecords
    GROUP BY pID
) t ON dbo.tblPat.pID = t.pID
INNER JOIN dbo.tblRec ON t.rID = dbo.tblRec.rID
```

Comment: I did the replace and I didn't get back:

(39  397 27/06/2008 13:13:49 27/06/2008 12:48:25)
(92  46632   04/10/2008 10:46:39 03/10/2008 19:26:04)

I get

(150 3092 04/07/2008 14:27:00 04/07/2008 14:20:26)
(218 12014 17/07/2008 14:54:51 17/07/2008 12:17:00)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SQL Server 2005 or 2008, then you can use the ROW_NUMBER function. Try this:

```
WITH Results AS (
SELECT  dbo.tblPat.pID, dbo.tblRec.rID,
        RIGHT(rPCheck, LEN(rPCheck) - (CHARINDEX('|', rPCheck))) as pCheck,
        RIGHT(rGP, LEN(rGP) - (CHARINDEX('|', rGP))) as GPCheck,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY dbo.tblPat.pID ORDER BY dbo.tblRec.rID DESC) Id
FROM dbo.tblPat 
INNER JOIN dbo.tblPatRecords 
ON dbo.tblPat.pID = dbo.tblPatRecords.pID 
INNER JOIN dbo.tblRec 
ON dbo.tblPatRecords.rID = dbo.tblRec.rID
WHERE (DATEPART(dw, dbo.tblRec.rDateRecAdd) IN (5, 6, 7)) 
AND (dbo.tblRec.rGP <> N'0') 
AND (dbo.tblRec.rPCheck <> N'0')
AND right(rPCheck, LEN(rPCheck) - (CHARINDEX('|', rPCheck))) > right(rGP, LEN(rGP) - (CHARINDEX('|', rGP)))
)

SELECT *
FROM Results
WHERE Id = 1
```